# Doing a Move and an edit in one Commit with Git TFS API in C#?

Tags: c#, git, tfs

I am trying to edit one of our files and also move it to another place in our repo and so far have this setup:

```
        GitRepository repo = new GitRepository();
        repo.Id = new Guid(RepositoryId);
        repo.Url = "Working.url.goes.here.com";
        repo.DefaultBranch = "heads/master";

        GitRef defaultBranch = GitClient.GetRefsAsync(repo.Id, filter: repo.DefaultBranch).Result.First();

        string result = testpath.Replace(ACTUALFILEPATH, "");

        GitCommitRef newCommit;
        List<GitChange> changes;

        GitRefUpdate newBranch = new GitRefUpdate()
        {
            Name = currBranch,
            OldObjectId = defaultBranch.ObjectId,
        };

        changes = new List<GitChange>(3);

            //the changes for the test being edited
            changes.Add(new GitChange()
            {
                ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                Item = new GitItem() { Path = result },
                NewContent = new ItemContent()
                {
                    Content = TestContent,
                    ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                },
            });

            //the changes for the csproj file
            changes.Add(new GitChange()
            {
                ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Edit,
                Item = new GitItem() { Path = projPath },
                NewContent = new ItemContent()
                {
                    Content = projContent,
                    ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                },
            });

            //The deletion of the old file
            changes.Add(new GitChange()
            {
                ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Delete,
                Item = new GitItem() { Path = origpath },
            });

            newCommit = new GitCommitRef()
            {
                Comment = commitmessage,
                Changes = changes.ToArray()
            };

            GitPush push = GitClient.CreatePushAsync(new GitPush()
        {
            RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { newBranch },
            Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { newCommit },
            Repository = repo
        }, repo.Id).Result;

        return result;
```

Everytime I try to run it, either the delete causes an error that says you cant modify the same file twice in one commit, or if I move the delete to before it says the file doesnt exist in the directory of the branch.

What I need: To be able to move a test from one directory to another, edit its contents, and also edit the contents of another file, and push all that to the server.

Other Notes: Use of Powershell and Cmd are very limited.

Any Thoughts or suggestions or know what is wrong? Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Quite a bit isn't shown, including what I think is the key point: based on those errors, it sounds like you're initializing origpath incorrectly.

Comment: You are quite correct sir, just figured this out a couple of minutes ago and was going to post it on here.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after testing for several more hours, I finally figured it out..

I was using the wrong argument for origpath, and was passing it the same path as the new file that I was adding.

TLDR: Double check your arguments when writing a function